# How do I use the data I have to make predictions?

Tags: correlation

I've a set of CPUs (~100). I've the results of each CPU being benchmarked against a suite of benchmarks (~8). There is a specific task that interests me, and I need to find the optimal CPU for that task. A small subset of CPUs (~10-20) has noisy measurements for how well it performs at that specific task.

Two questions:

- How do I use the data I have to make predictions about how well a given CPU will perform at that specific task (when its performance wasn't directly measured on that specific task)? This presumes that the large set of benchmark suite results have captured the CPU performance aspects that are relevant to that specific task. An interpretable white-box solution would be prefered, so I can tell which benchmarks are relevant for which task (and how relevant).
- How do you formulate this problem in a general way, so that I could research it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite pessimistic about this: ideally one would run the actual task (or a proxy for the task, like a simplified version of the task) with the 100 CPUs. Here the only option I can think of is to:

1. use the noisy measurements of the 10-20 CPUs as the basis of the data for the actual task
2. try to map these measurements to the 8 benchmarks, so that we can predict the performance of the 100 CPUs based on their results with the 8 benchmarks.

I'm pessimistic because:

- the measurements on the tasks are noisy,
- there's no guarantee that these measurements can be reliably linked with the 8 benchmarks,
- and no guarantee either that the 8 benchmarks would provide a good estimate on the task.

That being said, technically you could imagine a design with supervised learning, the idea being to predict performance on the task (target variable) from the results of the 8 benchmarks (features). The training data would consist of the results of the 10-20 CPUs for which you have both results (8 benchmarks + performance on the task). I would suggest trying this with decision tree regression because it provides you with an interpretable model (white box solution).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't have access to the CPUs for running additional benchmarks. I'll look at decision tree regression. I'm currently reading about non-linear correlation, but not yet sure how I'd use it.